# jquery fixed div on scroll-down

Tags: jquery, position, fixed

I have a gallery navigation bar which I would like to be fixed to the top when the page scrolls down too far. The script I have seems to work fine but there is a "jump" when the class is applied (transitioning between relative to fixed position).

**[Link](http://bit.ly/fbzMQA)** (depending on your resolution, you may need to minimize the page to see the effect).

**Code**:

```
<style>  
.HighIndex {z-index: 40; position: fixed; top: 10px;}
</style>
```

**Script**:

```
var msie6 = $.browser == 'msie' && $.browser.version < 7;

    if (!msie6) {
      var top = $('#navContainer').offset().top - parseFloat($('#navContainer').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
      $(window).scroll(function (event) {
        // what the y position of the scroll is
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();

        // whether that's below the form
        if (y >= top) {
          // if so, ad the fixed class
          $('#navContainer').addClass('HighIndex');
        } else {
          // otherwise remove it
          $('#navContainer').removeClass('HighIndex');
        }
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the jump accures because of `top: 10px;` in your CSS: all positionas are correct, but 10 additional pixels come from nowhere when class is applied. So you have two options here:

## 1

Remove `top: 10px;` from `.HighIndex` definition (which, I guess, you would not want)

## 2

Reflect those 10px in your javascript. This could look like this:

```
if (y >= top - 10) {
      // if so, ad the fixed class
      $('#navContainer').addClass('HighIndex');
} else {
      // otherwise remove it
      $('#navContainer').removeClass('HighIndex');
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply.
that didnt seem to solve the issue completely, but it pointed me in the direction - i realized that when the nav is pulled "out" of the flow of the page, the large picture just below it, actually jumps up to fill the space - so the jump is more of the large image, than of the nav bar.
So thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

i created an empty DIV that expands ti fill the space, when the nav is raised up. here is the code:

```
if (!msie6) {
  var top = $('#navContainer').offset().top - parseFloat($('#navContainer').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
  $(window).scroll(function (event) {
    // what the y position of the scroll is
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    // whether that's below the form
    if (y >= top-10) {
      // if so, ad the fixed class
      $('#navContainer').addClass('HighIndex');
      $('#navContainerSpacer').css('height','138px');
    } else {
      // otherwise remove it
      $('#navContainer').removeClass('HighIndex');
      $('#navContainerSpacer').css('height','0');
    }
  });
}
```